# Используя iptables, необходимо скрыть 22, чтобы его не было видно при сканирование (nmap и тд)

Tags: linux, ssh, tcp, iptables, port

У меня сложилась следующая проблема: мой препод по ИБ дал задание, над которым я мучаюсь уже n-ое кол-во времени. Суть всей задачи в чем, мне нужно каким-то образом **скрыть 22 порт**, чтобы его **не было видно в nmap и тп**, используя при этом по возможности только **iptables** то Но при всем при этом, чтобы я **мог подключаться по этому порту**. То есть, мог устанавливать соединение через тот же Putty и тп. Сам я уже неоднократно пытался сделать это различными способами, найденными в интернете, но ничего из этого мне не помогает.

Вот примеры некоторых попыток, что я уже сделал:

1. **iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP** - Нашел данную команду на форуме Habr, но порт так и остался видимым.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Уже не вспомню, где нашел этот способ, но он тоже не помог. Там необходимо было создать новую цепочку и добавить уже туда новые правила. Но в таком случае порт просто имел потом статус filtered и я не мог по нему подключиться.

Comment: По-моему требования противоречат друг другу: если putty сможет подключиться, то и nmap точно так же сможет подключиться

Comment: Единственное, что приходит в голову - это фильтрация по ip

Comment: Извиняюсь, я мало в этом понимаю. Кроме вот того, что ограничивал подключение для определенных ip. Но я опять же, только блокировал подключение, но не скрывал порт. Может быть есть какой-нибудь вариант, или мне ответить преподу, что такое сделать фактически невозможно?

Comment: Есть два уровня проблемы. Первое, это собственно постановка задачи. Как уже указал andreymal нельзя в общем случае оставить возможность подключаться к порту и закрыть порт. Второй уровень, это если уж принять, что постановка задачи заключается в том, чтоб сделать фильрацию по ip используя iptables. Это сделать можно. Нужно отбрасывать любые входящие пакеты на порт 22 кроме как с определенных IP.

Comment: а можно просто подключение для 22 порта принимать только с локалхоста. и только. А вот если Вам нужно подключится - использовать ssh, который умеет работать как сокс прокси. и все, сканируйте сколько хотите, порт никто не слушает

Comment: @KoVadim я не понимаю, как `использовать ssh` извне не открывая порт к порту ssh сервера? Перенести ssh сервер на другой порт - это же не решение оригинальной проблемы с открытым портом ssh сервера для всего мира.

Comment: ой,  я решил, что 22 это почтовый сервис. Тогда лучше использовать knock-knock механизм. https://www.howtogeek.com/442733/how-to-use-port-knocking-on-linux-and-why-you-shouldnt/ то есть, если ничего не делать - порт закрыт. Но что бы открыть, нужно знать "секрет" - постучать по нужным портам в нужной последовательности. Тогда порт будет открыт на какое то время для работы.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. В будущем разберу каждый вариант подробнее, а пока думаю не стоит задерживаться на одном месте. Впереди еще много лабораторных работ!

Comment: ну если препод задал, то логичный ответ будет открыть 22 порт только для нужного IP, в таком случае для всех остальных адресов он будет закрыт и для адреса препода тоже. nmap-ом он его не увидит. А ты сможешь заходить со своего IP без проблем.
Есть ещё неплохая вещь Port Knocking, putty  его поддерживает в настройках соединения. Суть его такова, чтобы открылся порт 22 (или какой угодно) нужно постучаться по определённым портам, двум, трём ... и после этого порт откроется. Рекомендую поискать настройки Port Knocking в гугле, довольно долго описывать.

Answer (score 1):

Если подходит вариант, что порт 22 будет доступен только с определенного IP, а для всех других будет выглядеть, что порт не слушается вообще, то такое решение:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ! -s xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Тут `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - IP с которого нужно иметь доступ.

Ассоциация https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284358/147662

Comment: главное nmap с этой же машины не запускать